# List manipulation Interval Intersection

Tags: list-manipulation, intervals

I'm having some troubles manipulating a nested list:

```
{{2.5285, 2.54381}, {1.77463, 1.0246}, {1.30668, 1.31949}, {0.986982, 1.78699}, 
 {1.71224, 0.00986564}, {0.733888, 0.768184}, {0.0570823, 1.71373}}
```

I need to remove any list whose elements are not in some `Interval[{0, x}]`, if the interval is [0, 1] I should keep only `{{0.733888, 0.768184}}`

The nested list may be of n elements `{{a1, b1, d1, ..., n1}, {a2, b2, ..., n2}, ...}`

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
list = {{2.5285, 2.54381}, {1.77463, 1.0246}, {1.30668, 1.31949}, {0.986982, 1.78699}, 
        {1.71224, 0.00986564}, {0.733888, 0.768184}, {0.0570823, 1.71373}};
```

Try:

```
Select[VectorQ[#, 0 <= # <= 1 &]&]@ list

(* Out: {{0.733888, 0.768184}} *)
```

You could wrap this in a function for convenience and to change the upper limit:

```
Clear[selectinterval]
selectinterval[upperlimit_][list_] := Select[list, VectorQ[#, 0 <= # <= upperlimit &] &]
```

which you can use as follows to achieve the same result:

```
selectinterval[1][list]
```